# REST API - Updating a Variable

Tags: rest, api, http, web-api

If you are updating a variable in a RESTful API, for example `person`'s `weight`, how should this be laid out?

What I have thought of:

- PUT `/person/1/weight?weight=150`
- PUT `/person/1/weight`

  `{"weight": 150}`
- PUT `/person/1/weight`

  `150`

There's been a few answers on this but I don't feel like it's been answered in a clear, solid way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are updating just part of the resource you should consider using [PATCH](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/) HTTP method.

Request format depends on your other API calls. Prefer consistency. If you use JSON elsewhere use JSON. Same goes for XML or whatever language you use.

I suggest using JSON, but I don't know how complex your API is.

Do, I'd do this:

```
PATCH person/1
Content-Type: application/json

{"weight": 150}
```